# ¿Cómo mockear un Path con nombres de atributo mediante Criteria API con JUnit?

Tags: java, jpa, junit, criteria-api

Necesito mockear un Path de Criteria API para hacer las pruebas con JUnit. El Path que quiero mockear es el siguiente:

```
Path<Integer> idPath = transit.get("object1").get("object2").get("id");
```

Yo he pensado algo como lo siguiente:

```
@Mock 
private Path<Integer> mockidPath;          
Mockito.when(mockTransitRoot.get("object1").get("object2").get("id"))
    .thenReturn(mockidPath);
```

De esta forma, el error es el siguiente:

> The method thenReturn(Path'Object') in the type OngoingStubbing is not applicable for the arguments (Path'Integer').

He intentado otra forma con :

```
@Mock 
private Path<Object> mockidPath;
```

Pero da un error de ejecución: `NullPointerException`.

Gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Por que querrías mockear esa parte? Por lo general, es interesante tener pruebas de integración contra la base de datos, para no tener sorpresas en runtime. ¿Cual es tu intención con la prueba que estás haciendo?